# What data structure supports fast insertion, deletion and search

Tags: search, data-structures

I feel like this has to exist, but I just can't think of it. Is there a data structure that can one hold a sorted list of values and be searched quickly (maybe log(N) time like an array), and also supports insertion and removal of elements in log(N) or constant time?

Comment: You didn't say which language, but a sorted linked list does all of that with a binary search algorithm (that is also used for insertion and deletion).

Comment: @kevinsa5, My understanding is that a linked list does not support binary search because it does not support constant time lookup, only O(N) lookup. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also this is a language agnostic question, I imagine such a data-structure should be implementable in any reasonable language.

Comment: Binary tree, then? Not contant time, but O(log(n)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much the description of a balanced binary search tree, which stores elements in sorted order, allows for O(log n) insertions, deletions, and lookups, and allows for O(n) traversal of all elements.

There are many ways to build a balanced BST - there are red/black trees, AVL trees, scapegoat trees, splay trees, AA trees, treaps, (a, b)-trees, etc.  Any of these would solve your problem.  Of them, splay trees are probably the easiest to code up, followed by AA-trees and AVL trees.

Hope this helps!